# java.lang.NullPointerException in Handler on dispatchMessage

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I'm new in Android programming and I have a sporadic error in a handler from a service. Log error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.rafag.taxialerta.RadarTaxiService$buzonMensajeTareaUbicaciones.handleMessage(RadarTaxiService.java:105)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is:

```
private Handler puenteTareaUbicaciones;
    static class buzonMensajeTareaUbicaciones extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<RadarTaxiService> wr;
        buzonMensajeTareaUbicaciones(RadarTaxiService srv) {
            wr = new WeakReference<>(srv);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            RadarTaxiService srv = wr.get();
            if (srv == null){
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                return ;
            }
            Message nuevoMsg = Message.obtain();
            switch (msg.what) {
                case PUENTE_OK:
                    srv.reciboSituacion(msg.what);
                    nuevoMsg.what = msg.what;
                    try {
                        srv.buzonMapa.send(nuevoMsg);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Line 105 is:

```
srv.buzonMapa.send(nuevoMsg)
```

buzonMapa is init at onBind to Service:

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return buzonServicio.getBinder();
}
```

And:

```
static class buzonMensajeMapa extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<RadarTaxiService> wr;

    buzonMensajeMapa(RadarTaxiService srv) {
        wr = new WeakReference<>(srv);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        RadarTaxiService srv = wr.get();
        if (srv == null) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            return;
        }
        srv.buzonMapa = msg.replyTo;
        srv.miSituacionEs(msg.what);
    }
}
```

In main activity, onServiceConnected:

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    buzonServicio = new Messenger(service);
    try {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.replyTo = buzonActividad;
        buzonServicio.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have this error one of hundred times, but I not able to find a patron to reproduce it always.

The general flow is:

```
Activity ----------------> Service --------------------> Thread
        buzonMapa<------------+  puenteTareaUbicaciones<---+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should check to ensure msg is not null before passing it to handleMessage()

Comment: Ok, but if is null, it's mean that my activity don't send the message to the service and the service don't have any way to comunicate back with activity. I'll add the code for service connection in main activity.

Comment: `srv.buzonMapa` is apparently null

Comment: That's what I think, but I don't understand why is that possible. I only have one point in app to start the service and send the value from activity to service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a possible cause to this problem. If the application crash for any reason, the service is recreated automatically by START_STICKY, but the reference to 'buzonMapa' is lost.

Answer (score 0):

It is a **weakreference**. So you cannot be sure that srv is not null or GCe'd. Check whether srv is not null.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, I check if is srv null, it's the first thing I do. 'if (srv == null){
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                return ;
            }'

Comment: It is a weakreference for a reason. android removes the reference when strong reference to the object is removed. So the OP should check for null at each step that he is going to refer to the value.

Comment: Ufff!, to heavy for my knoledge, you say that srv could be null two lines after execute `srv.reciboSituacion(msg.what);` just before enter in try?